# How to get a Btrfs filesystem fragmentation count?

Tags: btrfs, defragmentation, e4defrag

The **`btrfs check`** command output doesn't mention how many files are fragmented like **`e4defrag -c`** or **`e2fsck`** with **ext4** filesystems.

What command can give the number of fragmented files on a **whole Btrfs filesystem** ?